# #ignore markers is not working with contains only

Tags: karate

I am using karate for api testing.

i am reading expected value from csv "given '#ignore' in expected value"

And match `$.Response.Result[*].extendedInfo contains only "expectedvalue"`

assertion failed error:

```
 path: $.Response.Result[*].extendedInfo, actual: [001,112], expected: [#ignore], reason: actual and expected arrays are not the same size - 2:1
```

i want to ignore entire expected value/assert in once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got my Answer 
I want to pass ['#ignore','#ignore'] as expected

Comment: This will only work if you have two values in your array. And in that case, #present is better than #ignore.